# jquery tooltip - get attr returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery plugin, [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/), and everytime I try to get an attribute of the hover element, which is an svg shape, I get 'undefined', for example "**$(this).attr('id')**", whenever I use only the **$(this)** I get **"[object] [object]"**. So How can I access the attributes of the hover/clicked element like id, title? Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('circle').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span><img src="my-image.png" /><br>' + $(this).attr('id') + '</span>')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this`  isn't what you are expecting it to be .

A common pattern for initializing a plugin that requires element specific data passed to the options is to initialize inside an `each` loop.

```
$('circle').each(function(index, element){
    // now "this" is the element instance
    $(this).tooltipster({
        content: $('<span><img src="my-image.png" /><br>' + this.id + '</span>')
    });
});
```

Comment: that's did it, thank you, this each function wont affect the performance too much right?

Comment: @user1765661 no it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('circle').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span><img src="my-image.png" /><br>' + $(this).attr('id') + '</span>')
    });
});
```

Keep the `string part` and the `javascript part` seperate.

Concatenate it using `+`, like this.

`'<span><img src="my-image.png" /><br>'`**+ $(this).attr('id') +** `'</span>'`

Comment: so sorry, I do have the code like that, it was a typo when writing the question. Still returns undefined :/

Comment: @user typo, seriously? You dunno that such things as copy-paste exist?

Comment: Seriously, I was **NOT** expecting _typo_ atleast in code snippet.